# iPhone Chrome fails to read String Value of Var while filtering array

Tags: javascript, ios, arrays, string

iPhone web browser - Chrome or Safari fails to read the string value of a variable:

```
console.log(bigCities);
console.log(clickedWord);
var result = bigCities.filter(bigCities => bigCities.ar === clickedWord);
console.log(result);
```

While I'm on my iOS device and open up my site, I notice that the log for the result variable is null while all other logs exist.

After further investigation, and try/Error, I noticed that if I replace the variable `clickedWord` by actual string value, the site will function normally:

```
console.log(bigCities);
console.log(clickedWord);
var result = bigCities.filter(bigCities => bigCities.ar === "باب");
console.log(result);
```

I have tried several other ways to filter, includes... and I have also tried to transform the value of the variable and cast it as string:

```
var theString = clickedWord.toString();
var result = bigCities.filter(bigCities => bigCities.ar === clickedWord);
console.log(result);
```

The problem is that on an iOS device, filtering an array with the use of a variable is not working, while using exact string values works like a charm.

Has anyone faced this kind of issue before?

Comment: Where does `clickedWord` come from? Possible problem with character encoding maybe? Or extra whitespace?

Comment: @CBroe the variable comes from jquery-ui js, where i am using autocomplete. when i click on any suggested word, it gets stored in this variable. Logging the value everywhere shows that its getting correctly filled. But i don't know why it's not getting filtered,

Comment: try using == instead of === on your comparison with the variable and let me know please

Comment: Please post a MCVE, there is not enough information in the question to reproduce (and therefore understand and solve) the problem

Comment: @Tch i tried it, same result

Comment: the next think to try is either url encode both variables and compare the results, or base64 encode both variables

Comment: @Tch your comment actually made it! once i encoded it to base64, i notice that the iPhone automatically adds break lines! Please post it as answer so i could accept it and reward you the bounty!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the next think to try is either url encode both variables and compare the results, or base64 encode both variables